# Create and Use Android Library

Tags: java, android, eclipse

Sorry if it is a dumb question but i couldn't find an exact solution in this case. It is an important part of my homework and I have to create/use libraries.

**I have an Android Activity like:**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    TextView tv1;
    int i;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        tv1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);

        // HERE I WANT TO SET i = multiply(5);

        tv1.setText(i);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }
}
```

**And I want to create a library which includes a** `multiply()` **method like:**

```
public int multiply(int i) {
       return i*2;
}
```

I want to know how to create and implement this kind of library, also how to import and call this method in android app. I really need help on this case, and it would be greate if you can give some steps. Thanks.

Comment: FYI, there are 2 types of android projects: 1) App 2) Library. In your case, you need to create a library project. Include it in your app project and call whatever methods you want.

Comment: you can create a jar with the class and the required method. add the jar where you want import the right class and call the method required. If you have resources also then make a library project and reference the same in the required android project

Comment: @PareshMayani thanks i solved the issue through [this](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidLibraryProjects/article.html) article.